# How to intert image in SQLServer uing sql query without using parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert image in my databse .However I dont want to use the parameters as my set up of coding pattern does not allow this.Is there a way out?

I know that following code inserts the image

```
byte[] imageData = ReadFile(txtImagePath.Text);
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);
string qry = "insert into ImagesStore (ImageData) values( @ImageData)";
SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", (object)imageData));
//Open connection and execute insert query.
CN.Open();
SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
CN.Close();
```

But However, I would like to use some thing like this without the SQL Parameters

```
byte[] imageData = ReadFile(txtImagePath.Text);
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);
string qry = "insert into ImagesStore (ImageData) values(IMAGE DATA IN SOME FORM MAY BE 0101000101011001100 I dont know!)";
SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);
//Open connection and execute insert query.
CN.Open();
SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
CN.Close();
```

Comment: But Parameters is the way to go. In what way does your coding pattern not allow parameter?

Comment: You need to thoroughly rethink your "no parameters" coding practice - having parameters is the best defence against SQL injection. Not having parameters opens up the door to exploits and should be avoided at all costs....

Comment: @Albin It is because I am using a framework , where I will have to pass the whole insert sql as a string and there is no other way than to convert image into a bytes stream !

Comment: that sounds like a bad framework, it will give you more trouble than this. Floating point values and dates are sensitive to locale settings, not to mention possible SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Egads. And we wonder why, even in this day and age, SQL Injection vulnerabilities abound. Any such framework is a bad framework, as Albin says. You are going to likely have many, many other problems beyond this with this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-framed my question and I think I have got a solution plz Have a look at [convert image to stream of characters .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733026/how-to-convert-an-image-in-to-a-stream-of-characters)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used sqlserver, but can you use a blob where you can just insert any binary object regardless of format?
I found this article which may be of some help: http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3761486/Working-with-Binary-Large-Objects-BLOBs-Using-SQL-Server-and-ADONET.htm

Comment: It uses parameter So not the answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hex notation:

```
INSERT INTO imagestore
(imagedata)
VALUES
(0xFF01);
```

would insert a blob with two bytes (255 and 1) into the table

Comment: but How to convert image to bytes ... do you have any idea?

Comment: You already have a byte[] array. You just need to convert each byte into its hex representation.

Comment: If you insist on storing the image in the DB without parameters, the above answer seems best. Just do a 'Byte array to hex string' conversion and insert the resulting data. I wouldn't do this on multiple megabyte images though as the hex encoding makes it twice as big. For small icons it's probably acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Dont'!

Sorry for dodging your question, but why do you want to insert the image as a blob? In my experience it is almost never a good idea. Instead store the path to the image file on disk.

It could be that rour requirements leave you no other option than to store the image as a blob in the db, but I would seriously reconsider the requirements as storing binary (image) data is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I re-framed my question and I think I have got a solution plz Have a look here .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733026/how-to-convert-an-image-in-to-a-stream-of-characters

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:First converted the image into bytes then bytes into sting and inserted the sting using insert SQL, to retrieve the image I took back the steps!

```
    //convert to stirng
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:/bmp.bmp");
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg );
    byte[] b = mem.ToArray();
    mem.Close();
    mem = null;
    System.Text.UnicodeEncoding a = new UnicodeEncoding();
    string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode .GetString(b);
    //test
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:/txt.txt", s);

    //convert back to image
    Image newImage;
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        ms.Close();
    }
    //test 
    pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
    //It works!
    //So just fire the SQL
   con.Executenonquery("insert into ImageDb ('img') values (" + s +")") ;
```

Comment: I think you are just lucky that it works.

In fact there are definitely byte combinations that do not map to a valid Unicode character. There are approx. 100.000 Unicode characters that are encoded into bytes using either UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. If you are using UTF-8 (I can't tell from your code) then there are so called 'surrogate pairs' and not all byte combinations are valid. If you use UTF-32 there a 4 billion possible combinations which definitely don't all map to 100.000 characters.

In short: Don't use this code as it will probably fail at some point and will be impossible to debug.